# Are local variables in static methods also static?

Tags: java, memory-management, static, static-methods

I am wondering do all the local variables become static if we declare them in a static method ?

for example:

```
  public static void A(){
        int x [] = {3,2};
        changeX(x);

        for (int i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
             System.out.println(x[i]);   // this will print -1 and 1
        }
  }
  private static void changeX(int[] x){
        x[0] = -1;
        x[1] =  1;
  }
```

As far as I understand that Java is pass by value always, but why the state of X has changed after we made the changeX call ? Can anyone explain that please ? and can anyone explains how does Java deal with static variables in terms of memory allocation ? and what happen if we pass a static variable to a function as a parameter (I know people won't normally do that)

Comment: This makes no sense since static has no meaning for local variables. They are local, period, whether they are in a static method or an instance method.

Comment: It a local or temporary variable. After the function is over, it has no scope.

Comment: Array is an object in java. The reference of the array is passed to changeX when it is called, so its elements in the array can be changed within changeX.

Comment: You've got about five different concepts confused here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer to most of your questions is "the same as any other variable."

Local variables in static methods are just local variables in a static method. They're not static, and they're not special in any way.

Static *variables* are held in memory attached to the corresponding `Class` objects; any objects referenced by static reference variables just live in the regular heap.

When you pass a static variable to a method as an argument... absolutely nothing interesting happens.

*Regarding the scenario in your code:*

1. Imagine that you have a toy balloon on a string (the balloon is your array object, and the string is the reference to it declared in `A()`.)
2. Now you tie *another* string on to the balloon and hand that string to a friend (that's exactly what happens when you call the `changeX()` method: the string is the parameter of the method, and it points to the same object.)
3. Next, your friend pulls in the string, takes a black marker and draws a face on the balloon (this is like the `changeX()` method modifying the array).
4. Then your friend unties his string, leaving just your string attached to the balloon (the method returns, and the local variable in `changeX()` goes out of scope.)
5. Finally you reel in the string and look at the balloon: of course, you see the face (your `A()` routine sees the changed array.)

It's really as simple as that!

Comment: Can you explain the code above why the state of X changed after that function call ?

Comment: @user1389813: that has nothing to do with *static* and all to do with understanding reference variables. Please read what java-ranch has to say about variables.

Comment: but i thought java is always pass-by-value

Comment: It is pass by value, but for reference variables, the value is the reference itself.

Comment: @user1389813: Reference is the value of that variable. I hope you're getting my point.

Comment: no i don't get it..i thought for reference variable (non-primitive) is sort of like pass-by-sharing..meaning as long as you don't make any modification on the obj..they both point to the same reference...and in the example above...obviously the changeX function makes some changes on X..so that means now X points to a different reference, whereas the X in method A is still pointing to the original reference, so when we print out X in method A...it should print the original value...am I correct ?

Comment: @user1389813 -- I added a section at the end of my answer to explain your code's behavior. It's actually very simple -- don't overanalyze it.

Comment: The simile of a reference to a balloon string is probably the best I've seen.

Comment: There are suppose 20 variable members(array) in that static class. But only one is consumed at a time on "conditional basis". Do you think it's good to define them as local variables in some static method inside that class or 20 static variables? In latter, they're most likely to be stored in heap as permanent vs those 20 local vars. I'm confused since execution code for static method is also loaded in same memory. So, is there any benefit, or are both approaches same?

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the variables which are local to a METHOD are the same as any other variable declared within any other method -- they are dynamically allocated and may be freed when the method returns the the variable is no longer visible.

However, if you need static variables, you would have to declare them outside the methods, as ordinary static variables for a class.  If, by convention, you leave them alone except when inside that particular method, they have the same effect as if they were static and local to the method.  Just be sure to add comments to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are stored in a special area of the heap called the "permanent generation".

Local variables delcared in a static method do not make any difference with those declared in a non-static method. Object references and primitive variables are placed on the stack.Whenever you create an object, the storage is allocated on the heap when that code is executed.