# Java - local variables in static method

Tags: java, static

Since inside static methods we:

> 1. Cannot make static reference to a non-static field

2. Then a local variable in a static method **SHOULD** be **static** as
   well.

But according to this answer here: [Are local variables in static methods also static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645914/are-local-variables-in-static-methods-also-static/10645921#10645921)

> 3. Local variables in static methods are just local variables in a static method. They're **not static**, and they're not special in any way.

There is a conflict between my deduction (2) and the statement taken from Ernests answer (3) which I cannot explain.

Could someone explain if my deduction is wrong, and why is that?
And if I am not wrong what is the correct answer to the question "Are local variables in static methods also static" ?

**EDIT:** I am **NOT** confused by what a **local variable** OR a **member variable (field)** OR a **static** is.

I just thought that:
**IF** `"static methods cannot make reference to non static field"`  **AND** `"fields are variables"`
**THEN** `"variables in static methods are also static"`
making a variable in a static method **both** local && static

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think a local variable is static?

Comment: Seems you need to examine [that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: @immibis Don't forget that the word `field` is just a naming convention used to describe `member variables`. So a field is a variable type, just like a `local variable` is a variable type. Of course they are not the same type.

Comment: @Xipo Don't forget that the phrase `member variable` is just a naming convention used to describe `fields` (in some languages other than Java).

Comment: @immibis I agree with you, the only thing I wanted to point out is that fields are variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A field cannot be referred by a static method because it belongs to an ***Instance*** of a *Class* and therefore it is out of the static method's **scope**.

Local variables are never static. By "local" variables, it is understood variables declared and used in a code block, whether that code block be a static initializer, class initializer or method/constructor body. The **scope** of such variables is of course determined by the code block they are declared in.

Not to be mixed with variables declared in classes (fields), whether they be instance variables (non static; one per instance) or class variables (static; one per class).

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is not a field.

Comment: @Xipo You implied it: `"Cannot make static reference to a non-static field"` >> `Then a local variable in a static method SHOULD be static as well`. That's what I understood at least.

Comment: Ok I get it, I am just saying that I was literal and was not implying anything. I explain myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991291/java-local-variables-in-static-method/26991343?noredirect=1#comment42520615_26991291).

Answer (score 1):

1. Variables declared inside a method live on the stack. These are called **Local** variables
2. Variables declared as static live in the class. These are called **Class** variables. (though they are often referred to as static variables)
3. Variables declared nonstatic inside the class live inside the specific instance. These are called **Instance** variables.

Basically every time you enter a static or nonstatic method, memory is reserved for each variable you declare inside that block. This memory is freed when the block is exited. (exit from a method, or exiting a { } block. The lifespan of local variables is always the block you declare them in.

Answer (score 0):

The simple conflict in your exception is that you expect a local variable to be a field. Which is not true.

A local variable is just living inside a method. Where it doesn't matter if this method is private, public, static, final or anything else.

While a field is living with the Object instance.

And a static field is living with the class.