# Are the variable declared inside main in java static by nature?

Tags: java, static-methods

Since static methods can access static variables . So any variable inside       them should be static . Is this correct ?

```
class abc
{
public static void main (String xc[] )
{
int  a;  // Is variable a static ? 

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are local variables in static methods also static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645914/are-local-variables-in-static-methods-also-static)

Comment: variables defined within static methods is not static, as post-method execution the gc collects objects used within the method and throws them away. In other words; variables is treated the same way as non-static methods :).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are simple local variables.

It's actually not possible to declare static variables within static methods.

```
class Test
{

    public static void main (String args[] )
    {
        static int  a;
        a = 1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

doesn't compile while

```
class Test
{
    static int  a;

    public static void main (String args[] )
    {
        a = 1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

does